# Xamarin.Android The type or namespace name 'PlacePicker' could not be found

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play-services

Here is my issue after update to google play 42.1021.0 I cant find `PlacePicker` in `Android.Gms.Location.Places.UI`

PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

error

```
 The type or namespace name 'PlacePicker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (DSP.Droid.Client)
```

any one can tell me what using should  I use

Comment: Looks like a bug in the library. I suggest following (and commenting on) this [Xamarin Forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94933/google-play-services-places-version-42-1021-0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found answer  According to this [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93318/missing-android-gms-location-places-ui) I need to install this package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places/